# lftp behind firewall – what ports need to be opened?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, tls, lftp

I need to setup a secure file transfer from Linux client to z/OS ftp server using TLS 1.2 secure protocol. I am trying to use the lftp client for this purpose.

My Linux server is behind a firewall. I know that z/OS host accepts connections on port 990. So I requested this port to be opened in the firewall, but still the connection fails with timeout.

From lftp log I can see that it tries to open some other ports but fails:

```
---- Connecting data socket to (9.17.211.82) port 35854
**** Socket error (Connection timed out) - reconnecting
```

It makes many attempts each time to new port.

**The question is which ports I need to request to be open for lftp to work?**

I am on Red Hat:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.7 (Maipo)"
```

Using lftp Version 4.4.8

```
lftp -v
LFTP | Version 4.4.8 | Copyright (c) 1996-2013 Alexander V. Lukyanov

LFTP is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with LFTP.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

Send bug reports and questions to the mailing list <lftp@uniyar.ac.ru>.

Libraries used: Readline 6.2
```

Comment: FTP does not transmit over the port on which the connection is initiated. The server sends back a `PORT` directive telling the client on which port to connect for data transfers. Can you change the configuration of the server itself? If so you should change the server to use passive mode: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Comment: Thank you Slhck, very useful link. So looks like I need to interlock with server side guys, and request information about the range of ports that server uses for passive connections, and then request client administrators to open this range of ports on firewall.

Answer (score 0):

If you are beheind a firewall or router you have to use "passive" FTP.

In "regular" FTP, the server tried to connect back to the client, but initiating a connection from server to client is often not possible. "passive" FTP only uses connections initiated form the client.

All FTP clients support passive FTP, you just have to figure out the option. In plain FTP commands, this is the `PASV` command IIRC.

Comment: Thank you xenoid, But I speak not about ftp. I can not use it, because it is not secure.
I need secure TLS 1.2 connection and lftp supports this protocol.

Comment: A well-configured firewall should track FTP back-connections fine.

Comment: Thank you, Vonbrand.

Comment: Thank you, Vonbrand. After I studied the document by the link above, provided by Slhck, I contacted administrator of FTP server and got the range of ports, from which server can randomly select port to propose client for communication. Then I requested firewall administrator to open this range of port. Now my request is on hold. They advising whether they can open this range. 
Is my request correct from the point of firewall security? What do you mean by well-configured firewall. Appreciate any advice or link to documentation on how it is usually done.

Comment: Found another link, describing the subject from the side of firewall. https://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ftp_and_firewalls.html